# How to use asp.net controls in .JS file for SharePoint Development

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, csom, asp.net, jsom

I am working on JS file from SharePoint designer and using HTML controls inside my JS. I am willing to replace HTML Controls with asp.net controls for the user interaction.

Can any one help me in knowing the possibility of using the controls in JS file from SharePoint designer?

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot to understand your requirement?

Comment: is my answer helps you?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The answers very much vary depending on your end-goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP controls in your JS file using below mentioned code.
For example, If you want to access button in your JS file than you can use
`document.getElementById('<%=btnXXXX.ClientID%>')`

ASP control's IDs change on runtime so you have to get those controls using their id on client side like mentioned above.

Comment: I want to create the controls in .JS file and use it.Is there any thing to register to use in .JS file

Comment: You can get reference to create ASP controls in JS & use it from this link....http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-dynamic-textbox-using-JavaScript-in-ASP.Net.aspx